# for any subset S of 100 vertices of G, there is some vertex v for which all 100 vertices s ∈ S have a directed edge v → s?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How can I prove that one can construct a finite tournament $G$ with at least $101$ vertices such that: for any subset $S$ of $100$ vertices of $G$, there is some vertex $v$ for which all $100$ vertices $s \in S$ have a directed edge $v \to s$?

My attempt:

Add $100$ more vertices to the graph, and for each of these vertices, create a directed edge from the source vertex to that vertex. This ensures me there is a directed edge from the source to each of the $100$ vertices.

For each of the $100$ vertices I have added create a directed edge from $v$ to that vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to do, but easy to prove possible. It's the second example in Alon and Spencer's The Probabilistic Method, and is a classic instance of the genre: we prove the existence of an object with a required property by showing that a randomly selected object has this property with non-zero probability.

Here, let's rename $100$ as $k$. A finite tournament is a directed graph where each pair of vertices has a single directed edge between them. Pick a number $n$ and choose a random tournament on $n$ vertices: for every pair of vertices, flip a fair coin to decide if the arrow goes one way or the other.

For any set $S$ of $k$ vertices and any particular vertex $v$ not in the set, $v$ beats everyone in $S$ with probability $2^{-k}$. Thus $v$ fails to do so with probability $1-2^{-k}$. There are $n-k$
candidate vertices outside of $S$, so the probability that all of them fail to beat $S$ is $(1-2^{-k})^{n-k}$.

The point is, even though $2^{-k}$ is a very small probability for $k=100$, and therefore $1-2^{-k}$ is almost a certainty, raising this to a high power of $n-k$ makes that certainty small again. In other words, for large enough random tournaments, an arbitrary set $S$ is very likely to be beaten by someone.

So likely, in fact, that we can expect this to hold for all subsets $S$ of $k$ vertices. There are merely $\binom{n}{k}$ such sets, so if

$\binom{n}{k}(1-2^{-k})^{n-k}<1$

there is a positive probability that all sets $S$ will have an external vertex that beats all of them. This inequality holds for sufficiently large $n$.

This takes some thought to organize in one's head: there are many negations around, which I still get confused by. But follow this slowly step by step and you'll see that there must be a point in the probability space in which all of those failures (not having a beating vertex) fail.

The second challenge with understanding this proof comes from the contrast between the largeness of $\binom{n}{k}$ and the smallness of $(1-2^{-k})^{n-k}$. Who wins? I've written many such inequalities while working on my PhD, but I know I'll never be able to see them like they're flowers in a vase right in front of me, the way Noga  I does.

Anyway, this one isn't particularly hard. For fixed $k$, the binomial coefficient grows polynomially and the tiny probability decays exponentially, so we're fine. In fact Alon and Spencer use a couple of estimates to show that $n=k^22^k(\ln 2)(1+o(1))$ is sufficient.

It is far from easy to actually construct such a tournament even for small values of $k$. The magic of the probabilistic method is that we don't need to do that.